# Do we have any methods to prevent dialog box from appearing when the same dialog box is already opened?

Tags: javascript, dialog, appearance

I'm trying to fix the multiple dialog box appearing issue, where upon pressing fn key, dialog box appears to get input from user.Whenever i press fn key,the dialog box appears even when one of same dialog box is already opened.Then user needs to press cancel multiple times to close this dialog box. So i need to prevent this multiple dialog box from appearing when it is already opened.Condition to open dialog box is written in Js

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried in your quesion so that community can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You have not described specific dialog box you use, so I created a sample one and demonstrated the solution.
What you should do it to implement a singleton design pattern, and Here is a sample Code I wrote in codepen.
JS:

```
class singleModal{
  static isOpen=false;
  static id='dialog';
  static openModal(){    
    if(!singleModal.isOpen) {
      console.log("modal opened!")
      singleModal.isOpen = true;
      document.getElementById(singleModal.id).style.display='block';
    }
  }
  static closeModal(){    
    if(singleModal.isOpen) {
      console.log("modal closed!")
      singleModal.isOpen = false;
      document.getElementById(singleModal.id).style.display='none';
    }
  }
}


 singleModal.id = 'myDialog';
function openModal(){
singleModal.openModal();
}
function closeModal(){
singleModal.closeModal();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dialog" id="myDialog">
  Dialog
</div>

<button onclick="openModal()">open</button>
<button onclick="closeModal()">close</button>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/farshad-kazemi/pen/WNZrpoa?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks for solution and my code as follows:                                                                                            function key(g) { if (g.which == 116 ) { dialogbox('Confirm', 802044, undefined, 'BOTH').then(() => location.reload()); return false; } else if (g.keyCode == 82 && g.ctrlKey && !g.altKey ) { return false; }}

Comment: Here is a sample code considering your sample code.
Note that I had to mock your dialogBox function. Alsom you have to give the closeModal method for the close events.
https://codepen.io/farshad-kazemi/pen/jOGrJyq?editors=1111